# App Store reject - remove the bluetooth- values from the UIBackgroundModes key

Tags: iphone, ibeacon

My app using beacon functionality.
My app need to scan ibeacons when iPhone is sleeping and when its not sleeping.

I enabled capabilities: background modes
Also I enabled: Location updates and Uses bluetooth LE accessories

But Appstore rejected my application and write:

> Your app still declares support for bluetooth-central in the
>   UIBackgroundModes key in your Info.plist, but still does not provide
>   Bluetooth Low Energy functionality. The Bluetooth Background modes are
>   for applications that communicate to other devices using Bluetooth Low
>   Energy and the Core Bluetooth framework.
>
> Next Steps
>
> Please remove the bluetooth- values from the UIBackgroundModes key.

Why so? What I need to do?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This is easy! You simply do not need those keys to detect beacons in the background.  Go ahead and remove them and resubmit.

You need no special background modes for beacon detection.  You just need to request location permission from the user.

Comment: >>>You need no special background modes for beacon detection. You just need to request location permission from the user.  ios 9.

Comment: But I need - if I disable location updates - my app dont scanning for any iBeacons!

Comment: [self.locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
    self.locationManager.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically = NO;

Comment: But when my App is going to background - no any updates for scanning iBeacons!

Comment: There are two beacon detection APIs on iOS:  Monitoring and Ranging.  Monitoring is allowed both in the foreground and background.  Ranging is generally only allowed in the foreground.

Comment: - (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didEnterRegion:(CLRegion *)region {
    NSLog(@"DIDENTERBEACON");
    NSUUID *beaconUUID = [[NSUUID alloc] initWithUUIDString:
                          @"anyID"];
    NSString *regionIdentifier = @"anyIdent";
    CLBeaconRegion *beaconRegion = [[CLBeaconRegion alloc]
                           initWithProximityUUID:beaconUUID identifier:regionIdentifier];
    [self.locationManager startMonitoringForRegion:beaconRegion];
    [self.locationManager startRangingBeaconsInRegion:beaconRegion];
    [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}

Comment: and its still not monitoring!

Answer (score 1):

> You need no special background modes for beacon detection. You just need to request location permission from the user.

AppStore dont approve application with location updates.
How I can scan iBeacons without location updates **in background** and be in AppStore.